# Javascript and C# Cross Compiling and Conversion

Tags: c#, javascript, compiler-construction

What are the various tools to cross-compile or convert Javascript to C# and back? And how to execute JS in C# or C# in JS? 
This is a popular question, and I will provide answers for it.

Comment: Make this "Community Wiki" if you want others to contribute!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Compile C# to Javascript**

- [SharpKit](https://code.google.com/p/sharpkit/) ([site](http://sharpkit.net/)) - Write and debug C# 4.0, compile to JS
- [Blade](https://github.com/vannatech/blade) - Write C# and compile to JS, Interfaces for DOM, HTML, CSS
- [ScriptSharp](http://scriptsharp.com/) - Write C# and compile to JS, jQuery supported
- [Saltarelle](http://www.saltarelle-compiler.com/) - Write C# 5.0 and compile to JS, LINQ, jQuery, NodeJS supported
- [JSIL](http://jsil.org/) - Compile CIL bytecode to human-readable JS
- [JSC](http://jsc.sourceforge.net/) - Compile CIL bytecode to JS, ActionScript, Java, PHP

**Run Javascript in C#**

- [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS) - Javascript on CLR/DLR Runtime, Ecmascript 3.0
- [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) - Javascript VM, Ecmascript 3.0
- [Jurassic](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic) - Compiles JS into .NET CIL, ECMAScript 3 and ECMAScript 5
- [MS JScript](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Feb/14/Evaluating-JavaScript-code-from-C) Engine - Legacy scripting Javascript engine

**Run C# In Javascript**

- [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) - Run C# code alongside Node.js, in-process

Comment: Saltarelle is not part of Bridge.NET - http://bridge.net. An open source C# to JavaScript compiler.

Comment: ScripSharp seems like derailed.

Comment: How about Compile Javascript to C#?

Comment: Now there's blazor webassembly, supported by .net.

Answer (score 4):

**Compile C# code to Javascript in Visual Studio:**

- [DuoCode](http://duoco.de/) - Roslyn based compiler that transforms C# to javascript

Comment: Sadly, they're not in business any more.

Answer (score 2):

[JScriptSuite](http://jscriptsuite.com) - compiles MSIL (C# or another .NET language) to JavaScript. Allows debug original .NET (C#) code, provides databind templates, remoting interfaces, controls