# Unity import native javascript as jslib

Tags: javascript, plugins, unity-game-engine, native

I have a script in `Javascript` ( not UnityScript ) and need to get it working in Unity. As I understand I need to change ending to `jslib` so it gets imported properly. But I have trouble using the actual script.

I am trying to make it work somehow with `DllImport` but with no luck so far. So if someone knows how to import `javascript` file and call it from `C#`, that would be awesome.

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag for questions regarding Unity game engine.

Comment: Are you trying to use JavaScript on the html side with the web plugin, or are you trying to use it inside Unity alongside C# scripts?

Comment: I am trying to use it inside Unity alongside with C# scripts.

Comment: You can always do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589800/unity-5-webgl-communicating-with-external-javascript-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

[jslib is used for interfacing with browser scripting when you're building on WebGL.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) The scripts that you use inside Unity should be either C# 2.0, UnityScript or Boo. UnityScript isn't the same as JavaScript despite the similarities, and you won't be able to use JavaScript with Unity other than as a "native" scripts running in the browser, alongside Unity plugin or WebGL.

Comment: thanks for your response. Ok, is there any other way to import javascript file into Unity and call its functions ? Its huge javascript file where rewriting it to C# for example isnt realy possibility. Can i somehow implement it as plugin or Dll or something like that ? I realy have no idea how to go around it, first time doing this. thanks

Comment: I don't think there's any out-of-the-box solution for Unity, but you can look at these translators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434389/javascript-and-c-sharp-cross-compiling-and-conversion

Comment: Hi,
Can i use javascript plugin in unity using a native Lib  on Android Platform?

Comment: You should ask a separate SO question about it.